# Why .first() won't work here?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I'm trying to get the value of the first div under "latest", but I keep getting "undefined". I'm expecting the value 5705. This should have worked, right? How do I set this right?

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function()
{
    console.log($('.latest').first().attr('lastValue'));
}, 5000); // refresh every 5 seconds
```

The html part: There'll be more divs added here. So 5705 may be 5710 or something else.

```
<div class="latest">
<div class="story" lastValue="5705">Story 5</div>
<div class="story" lastValue="5704">Story 4</div>
<div class="story" lastValue="5703">Story 3</div>
<div class="story" lastValue="5702">Story 2</div>
<div class="story" lastValue="5701">Story 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to select the first **child** and not the first **container**

```
$('.latest>div').first().attr('lastValue')
```

or

```
$('.latest').children().first().attr('lastValue')
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to select first child, not first element with class latest.

```
console.log($('.latest > div').first().attr('lastValue'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're selecting the wrong element(s), you *want* the `.story` elements, but you're *selecting* the `.latest` elements. Use:

```
$('.latest .story:first').attr('lastValue');
```

Or:

```
$('.latest .story:first-child`).attr('lastValue');
```

Or:

```
$('.story:first-child').attr('lastValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do this:

```
console.log($('.latest .story').first().attr('lastValue'));
```

or

```
console.log($('.latest .story:first-child').attr('lastValue'));
```

or

```
console.log($('.latest').find('.story').attr('lastValue'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.latest')` return an array of any elements which have `latest` in `class` attribute.

So `$('.latest').first()` return first element of this array.

In your example, HTML element `div.latest` is returned not the first `div.story`.

If you try : `console.log($('.latest').first().attr('class'))` you'll see what is matching by what you write.

It seems that you want to reach the first latest story, means first `div.story` element under `div.latest` element.
So try : `console.log($('.latest .story').first())`

My test with JSFIDDLE here : http://jsfiddle.net/lnplnp/yuMPf/